# react-redux: when mapDispatchToProps is object, how dispatch action works?

Tags: redux, react-redux

During the usage of `react-redux`, I came across a confusing point about the `mapDispatchToProps`, when it is an object instead of function.

For example, in my project, I have the following action creaters:

```
export const incrementBy2 = () => ({
  type: INCREMENT_REQUESTED_2,
})
```

And in my component I import the action creator and set it up for mapDispatchToProps:

```
import { incrementBy2 } from '../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// define the Home component, omit the details
const Home = props => ()

// omit the details
const mapStateToProps = state => ()

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  incrementBy2
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Home)
```

then in the component, I can access the action creator as `props.incrementBy2`, it also works well in my project.

My confusing point, `incrementBy2` is just an action creator, so how and where the dispatch take place?

Comment: source code is your friend https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js#L16

Comment: thank you.Yes, after visited my friend, it's much clear now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the official docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options):

> [mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function): If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.

Also you can follow [the source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/4d384029e3fa0355e762f40409a5dac4358a3de3/src/connect/mapDispatchToProps.ts#L25). There you can check the implementation details.