# Defining mapDispatchToProps As An Object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am just wondering for `Defining mapDispatchToProps As An Object` how can I pass ownProps to it? like in the function I can pass props as an argument.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  toggleTodo: () => dispatch(toggleTodo(ownProps.todoId));
};
```

for an object how to pass ownProps?

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  toggleTodo
};
```

My account got blocked by some down votes questions, the funny thing is I have to re-edit them, even though I already have the accepted answer.I do not understand what's the point to do this.I am so frustrated by this stackoverflow system.

Now, I basically can do nothing but keep editing my questions, and they have all been answered. This is ridiculous !!!

Comment: Is the answer to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51257013/5189811) helpful to clarify your concern?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule it does not say how to pass ownProps at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it correctly. Are you trying to pass ownProps to `const mapDispatchToProps` without having to declare `toggleTodo` as a method?

Comment: @Dhiraj `toggleTodo` is the action what do you mean without having to declare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You dont need to. You pass the props into each action as they are called and needed.

Long answer: 
`mapDispatchToProps` connects your actions to dispatch in the component so you can call the action and pass in required props for it using `this.props.action` instead of awkwardly finding dispatch and using `this.props.dispatch(action())` or similar.

I find it's simpler to connect your actions to your export and call the action  `this.props.addUser(prop1,prop2)` when needed - `onClick()`, `componentDidMount()` etc. It by default assigns dispatch to it without needing to do `mapDispatchToProps`. So

```
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    {action1, action2, addUser})(User)
```

then you can use:

```
addNewUser = () => {
  this.props.addUser(this.state.person);
}
```

where you pass in the props you're after and then do any other work the action or reducer itself (depending on your preference of flow) such as:

```
export const addUser = user => ({
    type: ADD_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: {user}
})
```

Comment: yes, I understand this, and I know the workaround is that convert the prop to a local variable and pass it to the function exactly like ur example, but sometimes I got a prop from a higher component, I wonder if I can pass the props directly rather than create a new `const`

Answer (score 1):

`ownProps` can't be passed to it without doing the wiring in `mergeProps` function passed in the `connect` function.

You see, when `mapDispatchToProps` is an object, [`whenMapDispatchToPropsIsObject`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v5.1.1/src/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js#L16) is invoked. It in turn invokes [`wrapMapToPropsConstant`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/wrapMapToProps.js#L3) which does this

```
constantSelector.dependsOnOwnProps = false
```

Now, this property is used to decide whether the action dispatcher should be invoked with props or not. See all `handle*` functions like [`handleNewPropsAndNewState`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v5.1.1/src/connect/selectorFactory.js#L45) in [src/connect/selectorFactory.js](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v5.1.1/src/connect/selectorFactory.js)

This is in contrast with what happens when `mapDispatchToProps` is a function. In this case, [`wrapMapToPropsFunc`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/v5.1.1/src/connect/wrapMapToProps.js#L38) when invoked wraps the action dispatcher and then invokes it with props.

Without passing mergeProps, you'll need to forward `id` prop to the action creator in the Component that is connected with the `mapDispatchToProp`

*e.g.*

```
onClickToggleButton = () => {
  const {id, toggleTodo} = this.props
  toggleTodo(id)
}
```